# Concatenar resultado de SP en query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un SP que devuelve un resultado y ese resultado lo quiero agregar como columna dentro de una query pero directamente no me da ningún resultado en mi columna, el SP si devuelve resultado ejecutándolo de forma separada, ¿ Alguien sabe como podría agregar esa columna?

```html
DECLARE @MiParametro NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @MiParametro=valor from [Serie] WHERE Valor IN('123')

DECLARE @miVariable int;
EXECUTE @miVariable = SP_Compuesto @MiParametro

  select D.NOMBRE,E.NOMBRE,@miVariable from [Serie] A
  INNER JOIN [Inventario] B ON A.InventarioClave=B.InventarioClave
  INNER JOIN [catEstatus] C ON B.EstatusInv=C.catEstatusClave
  INNER JOIN [Articulo] D ON B.ArticuloClave=D.ArticuloClave
  INNER JOIN [Entidad] E ON B.EntidadClave=E.EntidadClave
  WHERE A.Valor IN('123')
```

```html
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Compuesto](
@numeroSerie varchar(50)
)   
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT          
        concat(serie.Valor
                ,'-C-'
                , right('00' + cast(SUM(IIF(proceso.catTipoProcesoClave in (7,21),1,0)) as varchar(3)) ,3)
                ,'-' 
                ,right('00' + cast(COUNT(distinct refurbish.FechaRecepcion) as varchar(3)),3)
                )  as SerieCompuesta
        
    FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.Serie WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Valor =@numeroSerie) serie         
    INNER JOIN dbo.Inventario inventario  WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON inventario.InventarioClave = serie.InventarioClave
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ProcesoInventario proceso_inventario  WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON proceso_inventario.InventarioClave = inventario.InventarioClave
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Proceso proceso  WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON proceso.ProcesoClave = proceso_inventario.ProcesoClave
    LEFT JOIN dbo.T_Equipos_Refurbish refurbish  WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON refurbish.Cdsn = serie.Valor  
    GROUP BY serie.Valor
END
```

y me devuelve un 0 en la columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es imposible saberlo sin ver el código del SP, revisa que todos los RETURN  estén retornando un valor válido.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el [RETURN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) después del select:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Compuesto](
    @numeroSerie varchar(50)
    )   
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @retorno varchar(150);


SET @retorno =(
        SELECT          
            concat(serie.Valor
                    ,'-C-'
                    , right('00' + cast(SUM(IIF(proceso.catTipoProcesoClave in (7,21),1,0)) as varchar(3)) ,3)
                    ,'-' 
                    ,right('00' + cast(COUNT(distinct refurbish.FechaRecepcion) as varchar(3)),3)
                    )  as SerieCompuesta
            
        FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.Serie WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Valor =@numeroSerie) serie         
        INNER JOIN dbo.Inventario inventario  WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON inventario.InventarioClave = serie.InventarioClave
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ProcesoInventario proceso_inventario  WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON proceso_inventario.InventarioClave = inventario.InventarioClave
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Proceso proceso  WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON proceso.ProcesoClave = proceso_inventario.ProcesoClave
        LEFT JOIN dbo.T_Equipos_Refurbish refurbish  WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON refurbish.Cdsn = serie.Valor  
        GROUP BY serie.Valor
    )

        RETURN @retorno 
    END
```

PARA EJECUTAR TU SP:

```
DECLARE @miVariable VARCHAR(150);
EXECUTE @miVariable = SP_Compuesto @MiParametro
```

Comment: es que el SP no regresa valor output ya que solo tiene un parametro, el SP solo tiene un select y a traves de esa instruccion me arroja el valor

Comment: por ejemplo que valores te retorna el Sp ?

Comment: pon una parte de tu SP , un ejemplo sencillo

Comment: ya he colocado el SP en el post

Comment: Ok ahora veo, te falta el return, voy a modificar mi respuesta

Comment: me aparece un error: La función o el procedimiento SP_Compuesto tiene demasiados argumentos.

Comment: mira que valor tiene la variable: @MiParametro , correrlo paso a paso

Comment: he modificado mi respuesta, agregué una variable de retorno.

Comment: hice los pasos y ahora me da un error de conversion al ejecutar el SP: Error de conversión al convertir el valor varchar '123-C-000-000' al tipo de datos int.

Comment: he modificado la respuesta. la variable que llenaras con el dato que retorna el SP debe ser de tipo varchar.